# How a json-rpc client can tell that a transaction it's sent has been rejected?

Tags: json-rpc, clients

Judging from https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC
the api client can synchronize on events such as:

1. Transaction is received/pending: `eth_gettransactionbyhash` returns non-`null` with block number `null`
2. Transaction is included in a block - `eth_gettransactionbyhash` returns non-`null` with block number non-`null`
3. Transaction has been executed as a part of accepted block: `eth_gettransactionreceipt` returns non-`null`

But if I sent a transaction that turned out to be invalid - how do I know it's failed, is there anything to wait for/react on?

UPD: There are kinds of errors that prevent transactions from even being included e.g. Insufficient balance for transfer (for the first transfer, not the nested ones issued by contracts), nonce too low/high. By "invalid" I mean transactions that produce this kind of error.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "invalid"?

Comment: There are kinds of errors that prevent transactions from even being included e.g. `Insufficient balance for transfer` (for the first transfer, not the nested ones issued by contracts), `nonce too low/high`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Javascript JSON RPC client library, like `web3.js` or `ethjs`, you will not get a transaction hash when you try to send a transaction that's invalid in the ways you describe (insufficient balance for gas, nonce out of order, address for which you don't have the private key or is not a test account, etc.)

Instead, you'll get a error that your code can either catch, or let propagate until it ends your program.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction
Here it's stated that no transaction hash in response means that the transaction is "not yet available". Maybe, all eth implementations actually return the error right away, but it's not specified in the main standard.